# IF/MATCH statement deemed FALSE on Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, match, excel-2010

[image]

I'm stuck with an IF/MATCH statement I'm using. I have used a similar one in a previous column that did work. The next time I tried it...FALSE. I've try and rewrite it but no success. Anyone has some feedback to it?

I'm providing a worksheet with the issues previously stated

Thanks in advance

This one throws: FALSE

```
=IF(MATCH(1,BASE!A2:Y2,0)=1,"Yes", IF(MATCH(1,BASE!A2:Y2,0)=6,"Yes",IF(MATCH(1,BASE!A2:Y2,0)=11,"Yes",IF(MATCH(1,BASE!A2:Y2,0)=16,"Yes",IF(MATCH(1,BASE!A2:Y2,0)=21,"Yes",IF(MATCH(1,BASE!A2:Y2,0)=25,"Yes"))))))
```

This one works

```
=IF(MATCH(1,BASE!D2:X2,0)=1,"Yes1",IF(MATCH(1,BASE!D2:X2,0)=6,"Yes6",IF(MATCH(1,BASE!D2:X2,0)=11,"Yes11",IF(MATCH(1,BASE!D2:X2,0)=16,"Yes16",IF(MATCH(1,BASE!D2:X2,0)=21,"Yes21")))))
```

Comment: It would help if you [edit] the post to include the formula you tried that failed.

Comment: I posted a pic with the data and the aforementioned formulas

Comment: It is better to have the formula as text and not a photo.  We cannot copy paste a photo.

Comment: BTW the issue is that the MATCH will return relative location of the first `1` and that is in column I which is `9` and `9` is not one of the choices.

Comment: So that's what it is! Well, at least now I know why the FALSE. Thanks for the insight. Have any suggestions for solving the issue, Scott?

Comment: I did in the answer below, if it meets your needs please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that MATCH does not know that you want to check every 5 columns and will return the first match in the range provided.   This match is finding the `1` in `I` and returning `9`.  This is not one of your choices and the `IF` returns `FALSE`.

We can use a different formula to return what you want:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(A2:Y2)-1,5)=0)*(A2:Y2=1)),"Yes","No")
```

The MOD makes sure it falls on the columns 1,6,11,16,21 and the next makes sure at least one of those is `1`

[image]